# Include an HTML code for a preview without overriding CSS of the containing page

Tags: php, html, css

I've created an email editor to allow my users created their custom email messages. 
The page that contains the editor has also a preview of the custom email, in PHP `<div id="email_preview"><?= $email_preview ?></div>`.

The problem is that if the user types in some CSS, than the elements of the containing page can be modified.

Is there a way to make the preview not influence the containing page?

Answer (score 0):

The most common way for doing this is by using an iFrame, or setup a styling convention/script. By using an iFrame you can keep their content/styling separate from its container.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. Sites like codepen, jsfiddle, and even Stack Overflow's code snippets use this method to keep things isolated. This really is the best option

Answer (score 0):

Your code `<?= $email_preview ?>` is outputting markup to the page when it loads. So all of the CSS they've entered is present in the page and your browser will render it accordingly.

The only way you could do this is if you stop the user inputting anything unless it applies to certain named ID's/classes.

For example if they enter

```
p {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Before saving this - and outputting it with `<?= $email_preview ?>` you could change it to:

```
#email_preview p {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

This means their CSS is only applied within `#email_preview` as opposed to all `p` elements on the rest of the page.

The other option would be to load the content in a modal window which excludes anything other than the markup stored in `$email_preview`. This is basically a blank web page with no other markup so it can only affect the intended content. This is like isolating the content within a page but is useful for preview purposes like this (amongst other things).

Comment: I'll remove it now that you've removed "No it's not possible".

Comment: I meant in the current state of his code, because the CSS had already been output with the rest of the markup. It's impossible unless it's targeted, or isolated, neither of which he was doing.

Comment: Say something more like "It's not possible without changing *this*" next time

Answer (score -1):

Rewriting all of the styles of the inbound HTML is the other alternative. (prefixing the styles or similar).